# Can x86-64 return instruction cause a page fault in linux? Is the current process stack always in main memory?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, x86-64, disassembly, page-fault

I know a return instruction will transfer "program control to a return address located on the top of the stack" [(page 1205)](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf).

1. Is the stack for the current process always in memory?
2. Assuming I return to a function in my own program (a near return?), then am I guaranteed no page fault?
3. Do far returns cause a page fault if return passes control back to code in another segment that is not in memory (like for a context switch maybe)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Nothing about `ret` or call/return in general is special as far as the CPU is concerned, or as far as kernel page-eviction algorithms.**  (CPUs do have a special branch predictor for call/ret, but that won't affect OS decisions about page eviction.)

---

User-space stack memory is demand-paged just like any other user-space memory (unless you use `mlock`).  `ret` pops a return address from the stack as `[rsp]`; this is the memory access that could make ret itself fault.  (Or of course if code fetch of the `ret` instruction itself faulted).

After ret successfully executes, code-fetch from the new RIP could also/instead page-fault if it happens to have been evicted.  (Or if a `call` instruction was at the very end of a page, the page being returned to might never have been touched.)

(And of course it's possible in hand-written asm, or with retpolines, to have mismatched call/ret.  e.g. something like `push`/`ret` as an equivalent to `jmp`.  Obviously you can jump to a page that's previously untouched or hasn't been for a while, leading to a hard or soft page fault.)

---

Nothing about `ret` or call/return in general is special as far as the CPU is concerned, or as far as kernel page-eviction algorithms.  The page containing `[rsp]` tends to be hot and not get evicted, but returning from a long `sleep(100)` system call, would give the kernel plenty of time to evict a page.  Especially if there was significant memory pressure.  Or if functions use significant stack space, they might be keeping a lower page hot, and eventually returning back up the call tree could be loading the return address from a page that hasn't been touched for a while even if the process hasn't been sleeping.